# How to use TeX Gyre Termes math fonts with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, tex-gyre-math

Currently I'm using

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}  % I load this first.
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
```

with *pdflatex*, but for math fonts mathptmx doesn't use TeX Gyre Termes, but it uses a similar other font.

How can I use TeX Gyre Termes in math mode with pdflatex?

Please note that in this question I'm not interested in solutions which need *lualatex* or *xelatex*.

Comment: Load `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`

Comment: You can't (at least not without lots of work). If you want a times based math font, use as suggested newtxmath which is mainly based on the txfonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there a significant difference between the appearance of newtxmath and mathptmx for casual users of math?

Comment: Yes, check e.g. the differences between \int and \sum.

Comment: Is this issue solved for you? How?

Comment: I've given up on this, other fonts were good enough in my use case.